# Objective-C - Should we use strong, weak or assign for Class-type?

Tags: objective-c, class

I know that we should use strong/weak for Obj-C objects properties/ivars. But I found that I can use strong for Class-type properties/ivars.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Class testClass;
```

The code will not cause a build error. Why? And should we use strong or assign?

Comment: Actually, `testClass` is an object too but it will be never released so it doesn't matter if you use strong/weak/assign for it. They give same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [The Secret Life of Classes](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch04.html#_the_secret_life_of_classes)

> A class object is not an instance, but it is definitely a full-fledged object
>
> You don’t have to do anything to create a class object. One class object for every class your program defines is created for you automatically as the program starts up.

Of course, you can use `strong` for an object.

*When is a class object released?* - Simple answer is when program is finished.

There is no reason to care about Retain Count of an object which will be never released while program is running. It means that doesn't matter if you use strong/weak/assign, this object is still not be destroyed until program is finished.

So you can use whatever you want, they will give same result.

Comment: A class object is never actually released;  there is no cleanup or any other kind of "end of life cycle" triggers on class objects.  The reaping that happens when a program is finished is external to the program itself.   In some (many) cases, the at-exit hooks won't even be called when the app is terminated by the user or the OS.

Comment: Personally I think this answer is bad advice. It's relying on an implementation detail. I would treat the property as you would any other. Use `strong` to indicate that you want to safely hold onto the value while you need it. Use `weak` to indicate that it's OK if the value disappears (even if it actually can't in this particular case). Declare a property based on how the property is to be used, not on some possible implementation detail behind the data type of the property.

Comment: "A class object is not an instance" Every object is an instance of something. A class object is an instance of a metaclass.